# How do I use FolderPicker result as a variable?

Tags: vba, excel

I added this section to the following code in an attempt to allow someone to pick a folder rather than it being pre-selected.

```
Dim diaFolder As FileDialog

Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
diaFolder.Show
```

It correctly opens up a folder picker and lets me select the folder but I'm not sure how to then use that variable correctly because `filepath = diaFolder` is now showing up as `"FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)"` causing   `Do While Len(myFile) > 0` not to trigger.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Dim myFile As String, filepath As String
    Dim wbc As Long, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog

Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
diaFolder.Show

    wbc = 0
    filepath = diaFolder

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'only try to open xlsm workbooks
    myFile = Dir(filepath & "*.xlsm*")

    'Opens workbooks located _Application Assurance\Maturity Assessments in order
    Do While Len(myFile) > 0
        'Make sure myFile isn't ThisWorkbook
        If Split(myFile & ".", ".")(0) <> Split(ThisWorkbook.Name & ".", ".")(0) Then

            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filepath & myFile, ReadOnly:=True)

            'Check if there is a Results worksheet
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Results")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not ws Is Nothing Then
                 'Transfer cells B2 & C2 from the results worksheet
                 With ws.Range("A2:B2")
                     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AMT").Range("B4").Offset(wbc, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
                 End With
            End If

            'Close wb most recently opened
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

            wbc = wbc + 1
            If wbc > 1000 Then Exit Do

        End If

        Set ws = Nothing
        myFile = Dir
    Loop

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `.selecteditems(1)`

Comment: Sorry @Nathan_Sav not sure where that's meant to go. Will google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `diaFolder.Show` and include:

```
If diaFolder.Show = -1 Then
    myfile = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)
End If
```

This will jump the allocation if `Cancel` is pressed.

Comment: `myFile = Dir(filepath & "*.xlsm*")` is now showing the correct file path but     `Do While Len(myFile) > 0` is still showing as empty and the loop isn't triggering. Thoughts?

Comment: Try `Debug.Print`ing the selected folder: you might have to add a backslash before `*.xlsm*`